# how to print all values under a column in wikipedia table?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, python-requests, wikipedia

i am scraping COVID-19 data from wikipedia table into pandas dataframe. when i print the cases column in the wikipedia table, i was expecting all the values under column "cases" to be printed but only the last value in the column was printed in dataframe. this is my code below.i want to print all value under the "cases" column. please how can i do this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
html= requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_in_Nigeria")
bsObj= BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')

for items in bsObj.find("table",{"class":"wikitable sortable"}).find_all('tr')[1:37]:
    data = items.find_all(['th',{"align":"left"},'td'])
    #print(data)
    state = data[0].a.text
    #print(state)
    cases = data[1].b.text
    #print(cases)

table= ({"STATES": [state],
       "CASES":[cases]})
tab= pd.DataFrame(table)
print(tab)
```

Result

```
    STATES   CASES
0   Kogi       3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop overwrites the target values in every iteration, that's why you only get the last row. You need to store these values in a list and THEN convert them to a dataframe.

So change your loop to:

```
states = []
cases = []
for items in bsObj.find("table",{"class":"wikitable sortable"}).find_all('tr')[1:37]:
    data = items.find_all(['th',{"align":"left"},'td'])
    states.append(data[0].a.text)
    cases.append( data[1].b.text)
columns = ['States','Cases']
tab = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(states, cases)), 
               columns =columns) 
tab
```

Output:

```
    States  Cases
0   Lagos   8,177
1   FCT     1,489
2   Kano    1,182
```

etc.